# Is it possible to create a script that automatically blocks busy IPs in nginx?

Tags: nginx, block

We find the parsing IP once a day.

82222 123.123.123.123
76661 123.123.123.123
30207 123.123.123.123

Record the number of records and IP in the log in the form above.
How can I make this type of record into a script that can be added to the nginx deny list?

The nginx deny list is saved as below.

/etc/nginx/black.conf